# How to render empty element to dom in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a element to the dom that contains a empty value when the page is loaded initially

```
<small className="error-message">
   <p id="error-msg">{this.state.errorMessage}</p>
</small>
```

`errorMessage` is initially set to an empty string and I set the error message when some fields in my form are not completed

```
        this.state = {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            email: '',
            username: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: '',
            errorMessage: ''
        }

    async handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        if(!this.state.firstName || !this.state.lastName || !this.state.email || !this.state.username || !this.state.password || !this.state.confirmPassword){

            return this.setState({errorMessage: 'Please complete all fields'})
        }
```

My problem is that react wont add the `small` element to the Dom unless `errorMessage` is set. This makes my form expand vertically to show the error message. Is there any way I can make react render the `small` element regardless of what the value of `errorMessage` is so my form remains the same height?

Comment: React does not automatically hide elements, this would be caused by the fact that the DOM element has no content and no static height so it takes up no space and once the DOM element does have content it will automatically size itself to that content causing your change in height.

Comment: you can use css style and set any height and width you want for that element

Answer (score 1):

I would set a minimum height for the fragment:

```
<small className="error-message" style={{ minHeight: 30 }}>
   <p id="error-msg">{this.state.errorMessage}</p>
</small>
```

Comment: Yes. In this case, even a standard `height` will do.

Comment: well, yes, but it depends on the possible content of the `errorMessage` string. Suppose it bocomes long to wrap, a `minHeight` would solve better than a fixed `height`.

Comment: It's not actually adding the div to Dom until  ```errorMessage``` is set. So setting the height isnt fixing my problem. If I put random characters next to the jsx like 'asdf' It renders to the Dom.

Comment: @ArvindD. the `small` fragment is rendered all the times (at least from what you've written). What changes is the height of the elements, due the message content. Please, check with the DevTools how the things are going.

Comment: @MarioVernari Mario thanks for response. I checked the devtools and the div is rendering. I was able correct my issue by putting the ```small``` element in a materialUI ```<Grid>``` tag which has default height.